# Funky mouseenter / mouseout with Jquery.live

Tags: jquery, css, live, mouseenter

This seems to be a very common problem, although I've tried the recommendations to use addClass / removeClass rather than direct CSS manipulation, and I've tried mouseleave / mouseout but both cause problems.

All I want is a simple roll over that changes the class!  Everything I try either inconsistently flickers the class on or off.  The only other requirement I've been trying to accommodate is to have the listener live in a function rather than inline.  Is that what's making this impossible?

```
function highlight(_event){
  $(this).addClass("Highlighted");
}
function unhighlight(_event){
  $(this).delay(2000,function(){
    $(this).removeClass("Highlighted");
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () { 
  $(".Content").live('mouseenter',highlight);
  $(".Content").live('mouseout',unhighlight);
});
```

[JSFiddle of the above](http://jsfiddle.net/PUmkR/)

**Edit**

Adding `.stop(true,true)` seems to help quite a bit.

Comment: What are you trying to highlight?  Text, a div?

Comment: I'm not witnessing any issues with your example as you describe it (flickering). What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't label the JSFiddle link.  The styles are being applied to divs.  In both chrome and FF the effect is applied inconsistently on mouseenter / mouseout, but always eventually end up stuck in the highlighted state

Comment: see the update to the answer I posted, I read the comment you use the functions in other places so added to my answer to see if it helps out a little bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use live, you could do the following using [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), [`.mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover) & [`.mouseout()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout):

```
$(".content").live("mouseover mouseout", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

See a [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dqcNP/)

---

***Update:** I couldn't leave this one, so carried on messing with your example - after the comment you use the functions in other places. So here is what I found:*

Instead of calling [`.mouseout()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout) use [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave) - for some reason [`.mouseout()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout) get's called multiple times when the mouse moves round - it even gets called when the mouse first enters the object..... *See the demo at the end to see what i mean here*

Secondly, the [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay) isn't really being used correctly here - it is really meant for **queuing effect's** - but what you really want is to add a delayed function *(albeit it is an effect that you are after)* so instead use the [`.setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) to do the call for you.

[*As per the doc's:*](http://api.jquery.com/delay)

> The [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay) method is best for
>   delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it
>   doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay — [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay) is not a
>   replacement for JavaScript's native
>   [`.setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) function, which may be more
>   appropriate for certain use cases.

So the finished functions would look like this:

```
function highlight(_event) {
    $(this).addClass("Highlighted");
}

function unhighlight(_event) {
    var obj = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        obj.removeClass("Highlighted");
    }, 2000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".Content").live('mouseenter', highlight);
    $(".Content").live('mouseleave', unhighlight);  
});
```

See the [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/PUmkR/1/) *this one will show you what I mean about the [`.mouseout()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout) event being fired multiple times, where as the [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave) function is only called once when the mouse actually leaves.*
*Note: use your enter button to press the alert ok, don't move your mouse!!*

See the [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/PUmkR/2/) to see the final version working here as close to your original as possible.

Comment: Updated to try to answer closer to the comments below the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to, I think you can dump the functions and do this instead - if you aren't using the functions for anything else of course:

> $(document).ready(function () {
>     $(".Content").live('mouseenter',function(){
>         $(this).addClass("Highlighted");
>     });
>     $(".Content").live('mouseout',function(){
>       $(this).delay(2000,function(){
>         $(this).removeClass("Highlighted");
>       });
>     }); 
>   });

Comment: We're using the functions in other places.  I don't want to repeat the code, but I'm close to giving up and doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//Might be better to use .toggleClass("Highlighted");

var timer;

$(".Content").hover(
    function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $(this).addClass("Highlighted");
    },
    function(){
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("Highlighted");
        }, 2000);
    }
);
```